# How do I execute a stored proc starting from the URI of a certain collection

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

In an application I currently only have a URI pointing to a given collection. On this collection I wrote a stored proc. The proc works, no issues there, but I need to run it from within a .NET application.

I did some digging and found the following approach:

```
    public DataOverview GeneralOverviewByClient(int clientId, DateTime? fromDate = null, DateTime? toDate = null)
    {
        DataOverview result = null;

        // Get a Database by querying for it by id
        Database db = _documentDbClient.CreateDatabaseQuery().Where(d => d.Id == "XXXX")
                                                             .AsEnumerable()
                                                             .Single();

        // Use that Database's SelfLink to query for a DocumentCollection by id
        DocumentCollection collection = _documentDbClient.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery(db.SelfLink).Where(c => c.Id == "YYYY")
                                                                                                    .AsEnumerable()
                                                                                                    .Single();

        StoredProcedure storedProcedure = _documentDbClient.CreateStoredProcedureQuery(new Uri(collection.StoredProceduresLink)).Where(p => p.Id == "spGetData")
                                                                                                                                .AsEnumerable()
                                                                                                                                .FirstOrDefault();

        if (storedProcedure != null)
        {
            var response = _documentDbClient.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<DataOverview >(storedProcedure.SelfLink, clientId, fromDate, toDate);
            result = response.Result;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

However, it does not work, since my URI already points to the collection the statement `Database db = _documentDbClient.CreateDatabaseQuery().Where(d => d.Id == "XXXX")` fails.

I continued digging and found an overload in which I could pass the name of the stored proc (at least, that is how it seemed to me), allowing me to rewrite the code to:

```
var response = _documentDbClient.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<DataOverview>("spGetData", clientId, fromDate, toDate);
if (response != null) { result = response.Response; }
```

But I'm still not getting any results. What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the UriFactory over `_self` links (to avoid extra network round-trips) to build the reference to the stored procedure.

Try this:

```
var response = _documentDbClient.ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync<DataOverview>(UriFactory.CreateStoredProcedureUri("XXXX", "YYYY", "spGetData")).Result
```